# Gridview binding is lost when page index changed VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview, page-index-changed

I am using Ajax to call a `BindGridview()` class on code behind to bind the values from database. However, it only works at first time, when i try to change the page index on the gridview, it becomes empty. Below is my code.

I used `<%=PostBackString %>` to call the function on code behind.

```
 $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         url: "RepairStatusChart.aspx/BindRecord",
                         data: data,
                         dataType: "json",
                         success: function (result) {
                             <%=PostBackString %>
                             alert("Success");
                         },
                         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                          alert("Sorry, an unexpected error has occured.");
                         }
                     });
```

`<%=PostBackString %>` will jump to my page load to call the `BindGridview()` class

```
PostBackString = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, "MyEventArgumentName")
        If IsPostBack Then
            If Request("__EVENTARGUMENT") = "MyEventArgumentName" Then
                BindGridview()
            End If
        End If
```

This is my `BindGridview()` class which will set the data bind to the gridview

```
Protected Sub BindGridview()
        Dim partnum, ddlMonthFrom, ddlYearFrom, ddlMonthTo, ddlYearTo, repaircenter, finalstatus As String

        partnum = HttpContext.Current.Session("partnum").ToString()

        ddlMonthFrom = HttpContext.Current.Session("ddlMonthFrom").ToString()

        ddlYearFrom = HttpContext.Current.Session("ddlYearFrom").ToString()

        ddlMonthTo = HttpContext.Current.Session("ddlMonthTo").ToString()

        ddlYearTo = HttpContext.Current.Session("ddlYearTo").ToString()

        repaircenter = HttpContext.Current.Session("rc")

        finalstatus = HttpContext.Current.Session("status")

        Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("prcConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim select1 As String = "select CountFrequency, SRNo, RefurbishedSN, ShipmentDate, PartsNo, EmployeeID, Alias, Company, PartSN, StartRepairDate, DateReceived,  DateCreated, LastUpdated, EstimatedRepairCompletionDate, Status,datediff(curdate(),STR_TO_DATE(replace(DateReceived,',','-'),'%d-%M-%Y')) as Aging from testvsrparts WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(shipmentdate,'%d, %M, %Y') Between STR_TO_DATE('01, " + ddlMonthFrom.ToString + ", " + ddlYearFrom.ToString + "','%d, %M, %Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31, " + ddlMonthTo.ToString + ", " + ddlYearTo.ToString + "','%d, %M, %Y')) " + partnum + " AND  Alias ='" + repaircenter.ToString + "' AND  Status ='" + finalstatus.ToString + "'  ;"

        Dim dt As New DataTable()


        dt = conn.query(select1)
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

It works very fine until this part, but my problem is when I try to change the page index, its become empty. I have already set the `GridView1_PageIndexChanged` and `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` as below

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanged
                BindGridview()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
                GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
                BindGridview()
    End Sub
```

This is the screenshot of before and after the page index change.

**Before**

[image: ![Before]

**After click other page**
[image: After]

I would like to know what is the reason this is happening. Can anybody assist me to solve this problem? I really don't know how to solve this issue. Appreciate your help.

Comment: How many pages of data you have?

Comment: @AksheyBhat, the total rows for the data is more than 20K rows.

Comment: why are you binding  gridview twice in pageindexchanging and pageindexchanged events?

Comment: @AksheyBhat I tried using just pageindexchanging, but it did not bind as well. That's why I add another pageindexchanged. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have RaisePostBackEvent defined?

Comment: @AksheyBhat, no, i don't have.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112%28v=vs.110%29.aspx check this url for use of GetPostBackEventReference. you might be missing something